# How do I make a bezier curve to be more linear?

Tags: bezier-curves

I'm trying to make a simple bezier curve that is just a 90 degree drop from one vertex to another, but I keep getting this. Is there any way to fix this curl and just make it straight?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can change the **Handle Type** to **Vector** or **Free**. These two handle types allow you to manipulate each handle independently.

You can do that by selecting the handle and clicking <kbd>V</kbd> and selecting the handle type from the list.

[image]